# need help on image transfer over network

Tags: java, image, networking, image-processing, network-programming

I am trying to build remote desktop application using java. For that what I have planned is to take screen shot of screen using Robot and convert it to byte array(bmp image) and send it. In server side read image into byte array and convert to image and display. Successive images are compared with previous image and only different bytes are sent(along with start index where difference starts and length of difference). In server side I only read difference bytes and construct image.

Is this method suitable to use over internet(with moderate speed)?.

Please specify any better way to do it, if you feel this will not work on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds similar (at a very high level) to the [VNC protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc).

Rather than trying to invent your own, perhaps you could just adopt the protocol that it uses (RFB - remote frame buffers) or at the least look at it to get some ideas (using rectangles to denote areas of the screen that have changed sounds better than indices into a byte array).  The documentation can be found [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/staff/magi/doc/vnc/protocol.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But generally changes in screen does not change drastically always. Consider normal operation of editing text or moving mouse pointer.Generally small portion of image changes every time screen shot is taken. If this portion on is sent, then there is great reduction in network traffic.Please let me know if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: You aren't wrong, but I think indices into a byte array aren't the best way to do it.  VNC addresses this by sending a series of rectangular diffs.  Unless I'm not understanding properly, I don't think sending indices of a bitmap image is going to be as good.

Comment: Thank you.I'll go through VPN protocol and see how can it be adopted to my program.